# Object Oriented JavaScript shared method variables

Tags: javascript

Why doesn't this work?

```
function thing() {

    var bigvar;

    function method1() {
        bigvar = 1;
    }

    function method2() {
        alert(bigvar);
    }

    this.method1 = method1;
}

var a = new thing();
a.method1();
a.method2();
​
```

I want method2 to work, but it doesn't .. is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not make `method2` public like `method1` is.

```
this.method1 = method1;
this.method2 = method2;  //<-- missing this
```

Comment: to be strict, method1 is not made public, it is just declared as an assignment to local (or global, depends on implementation) function which haphazardly have "the same" name.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have `this.method1 = method1` but not `this.method2 = method2`? Try that.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do this?

```
function thing() {

    var bigvar;

    this.method1 = function () {
        bigvar = 1;
    }

    this.method2 = function () {
        alert(bigvar);
    }

}

var a = new thing();
a.method1();
a.method2();​
```